# Source maps not working in unit tests in Angular2

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-cli, source-maps, karma-coverage

I'm developing an Angular2 project generated by angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.18.

Generally the template has worked out very well. However, when I try to debug unit tests (in Chrome), the code is unintelligible.

What I do is:

1. I start the tests by running `ng test`
2. A Google Chrome browser opens
3. I can confirm in the console that the tests have run: `Executed 36 of 36...`
4. I now want to debug the tests, so I click the `DEBUG` button in Chrome, which opens a new tab.
5. In that tab I open the Developer tools.
6. I can now use `Ctrl-P` to find and view files. The code is readable for for the *specs*.
7. However, when I open the implementation code, I get the following

[image]

It looks like the file has been minified, or transformed by the code coverage tool. The latter seems more probable considering the `__coverage__` part. Sourcemaps are obviously not in effect.

How do I make source maps work?

I have tried modififying the `karma.conf.js` file to remove all references to code coverage reporting (i.e. Istanbul), see below. But this makes no difference in the behaviour:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This was actually a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1798). It was fixed in [angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.19-3](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta19-2016-10-28). Specifically it was [this fix](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1799).